# Why is my Bash script (OSX) running from the Terminal, but not when double clicked?

Tags: git, macos, bash, shell, if-statement

Here is the full text of my bash script:

GitC.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

git add .
git status
echo “Are you sure you want to commit and push? y/n”
read yn
if [ “$yn”==“y” ];
    then
    echo “Message:“ 
    read m
    git commit -m “$m”
    git push
    sleep 5s
else
    git reset
    sleep 5s
fi
```

I have run `chmod u+x` on the file, and selected Terminal for the default run Application, but when I double click on it, I get a response saying

> justins-mbp:~ Schwaitz$ /Users/Schwaitz/Desktop/JustWas/GitC.sh ; exit;

and the process will not continue. When I run it from the Terminal with the command ./GitC.sh, it runs perfectly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't you need a `.command` suffix to run a bash script in finder?

Comment: Perhaps a cut-and-paste issue, but your curly quotes look dubious, and you lack spaces around "==" in your if statement (BTW, better just write "=" than "==" to be POSIX compliant).

Answer (score 1):

The script makes the assumption that the *current working directory* is the same as the script, and I'm pretty sure that's not the case when activated through double-clicking in *Finder*.  It would also cause issues if you invoked the script like this:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

You therefore need to ensure it changes to the same directory as the script:

```
dir="$(dirname "$0")"
cd "$dir"

... etc.
```

Comment: The problem is, my GitC.sh file is IN the same directory as my git repo.

Comment: @kuuy That's OK; my answer should work in that situation.